# Permission denied while creating file or directory on /dev/sda1 in ext4 filesystem

Tags: permissions, gparted, ext4

I am not able to create a file or directory, it says permission denied. I am trying this in `/dev/sda1`. Here is the image from GParted & file manager :

[![image: permission denied while creating a new file/ directory]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQDda.jpg)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a *file* in gparted? What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am not trying to create a file in gparted. I am trying to create file in the partition dev/sda1 which I am accessing through file manager, refer to bottom half of the image with the tile "20GB volume".  Attached.image is a combo of gparted & file manager.

Answer (score 0):

That partition is the operating system partition.

The common user should **not have write and modify access to it**, as it can damage the system.

If you still want to try, you must log in, **which is not advisable**, as root with the file manager or in a terminal with command:

```
sudo mkdir
```

========================================================================
Edited - Move /home to partition:

You need to create a new filesystem on the partition.

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
```

To use the new drive, You must mount the partition on it to a mount point in the filesystem.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

You need to copy everything from the old home directory to the newly mounted filesystem.

```
sudo cp -rp /home/* /mnt
```

As a safety net, You're going to rename and keep your old /home directory until You’re satisfied that it is safe to delete it.

```
sudo mv /home /home.orig
```

And You’ll create a new, empty home directory.

```
sudo mkdir /home
```

You’ll use that new empty home directory as the mount point for Your filesystem on the new partition.

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/
```

Check that everything is correct in the new /home

```
cd /home

ls
```

If anything was missing, You could copy it out of the /home.orig directory, which we still have access to in the root of the filesystem.

You need to have /dev/sda1 mounted automatically every time your computer is started, find out the UUID of the partition and edit the fstab file.

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1

sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

You must add the lines at the bottom of the file to mount your new /home directory

```
Type the UUUI of the partition at the start of the line, (UUID= blkid /dev/sda1 UUID) and then press Tab.

Type the mount point, /home,  and press Tab.

Type the filesystem description ext4, and press Tab.

Type defaults for the mount options, and press Tab.

Type the digit 0 for the filesystem dump option, and press Tab.

Type the digit 0 for the filesystem check option.
```

Save the fstab file, close Gedit and reboot.

Once you’re perfectly sure that you no longer need the safety copy of your old /home directory, you can delete it:

```
cd /

sudo rm -rf home.orig/
```

====================================================

Edited: Clean the system

**I suggest you read about each command**

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall deborphan
sudo apt autoremove
sudo deborphan
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
sudo deborphan --libdevel
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
sudo deborphan --find-config
sudo dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
sudo apt clean
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
```

=========================================================

Comment: That helped. But what is the long term solution ? /dev/sda1 had Windows OS which I removed using gparted. It's an empty partition having unused 18 GB which I want to use along with my Ubuntu /dev/sda6 as it has only 2.8 GB space left. So, either (a) I should be able to merge these 2 partitions or (b) change the permission of /dev/sda1 for good so that I can move files across these partitions smoothly. So, I need help with either of these 2 options.

Comment: @user363628: You can move your /home directory to the empty partition, I am going to edit the post and put the procedure.

Comment: Thanks, the detail procedure helped. Partition /dev/sda1 - file system ext4 has mount point as /home now, with unused space of 17/18 GB. The partition /dev/sda6 - file system ext4 has mount point as /, with unused space of 2/17 GB. So, can I merge sda6 with sda1 so that entire 35 GB will be available for me ? If that's not possible how do I check & delete this 15 GB of data from /dev/sda6. I have taken backup of everything. Note - This entire 35 GB is on 1 internal HD.

Comment: @user363638: It is not possible to unite the partitions, not is it necessary, having left /dev/sda6 for the operating system, it would only be necessary to clean, I edit the post and explain how. As for your data, if it is not part of the operating system and is in a separate directory, you can move it to /home/user.

Comment: I will read about these commands and try them out. I have cleared all my personal stuff from HD, including recycle bin. I doubt if OS is taking 15 GB. Here's the background - this is a 2004 laptop - Intel Pentium 1.6 GHZ,1.2 GB RAM, 35 GB HD. It was running in dual boot mode - Windows XP & lubuntu 14.04. Dual boot has been removed along with XP. Lightweight ubuntu 14.04 taking 15 GB is highly improbable. Will clean the system and if that doesn't work maybe I will explore fresh installation of an lubuntu which this old hardware can support.

Comment: @user363628: https://mxlinux.org/mx-fluxbox/, This distribution is ideal for that hardware.